# GraphQL query to filter GraphCMS posts

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js, graphcms

I'm working on a GraphCMS site in React and would like to set up a GraphQL query to filter posts. We have this query setup which works and fetches all posts (adoptions) :

```
export const allAdoptions = gql`
  query allAdoptions($first: Int!, $skip: Int!) {
    allAdoptions(orderBy: date_DESC, first: $first, skip: $skip) {
        id
        name
        date
        image {
          handle
        }
        desc
        sex
        species
        neutered
    },
    _allAdoptionsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
`
```

The code is available here : https://github.com/foxreymann/foranimals/blob/master/src/components/Adoptions.js

We'd like to set up a filter component to get posts by species: "Cat" for example, and we've tried just modifying the above query for species: "Cat" with no luck. Any advice much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you check: https://graphcms.com/docs/api_simple/#filtering-entries?

It should work like this:

```
query {
  allAdoptions(
    filter: {
      species: "maine-coon"
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Michael

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael. I've tried that but I'm now getting an error : "Argument 'filter' expected type 'AdoptionFilter' but got: {species: \"Cat\"}. Reason: 'species' Enum value expected

Comment: I'm using the Apollo client for React and think that's the issue.

Comment: Hey! If its an Enum then you need to remove the ' " '. So ...species: Cat... will do the trick. Does species allow multiple values? Then this is not supported at the moment but will land soon.